# How do I display the user input when user clicks submit button. Also clear the message when user clicks the clear button. (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

How do I display the user input when user clicks submit button. Also clear the message when user clicks the clear button. (please & thank you)

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

    angular.module('exampleModule', [])

    .controller('messageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.message = '';

    }])
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="exampleModule">

  <div ng-controller="messageController">

    Input:
    <input ng-model="message" />

    <button>Submit</button>

    <button>Clear</button>

    <br/>
    <div>Message: {{message}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help ! @Anokrize

Comment: Glad you got it working:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your buttons a ng-click event and handle the event in your controller. 
If the submit button is pressed set the show veriable to true, so that it will display.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="exampleModule">
    <div ng-controller="messageController">

         Input:
        <input ng-model="message" />

        <button ng-click="display()">Submit</button>

         <button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>

         <br/>
         <div ng-show="show">Message: {{message}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
angular.module('exampleModule', [])
.controller('messageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.show = false;
    $scope.message = '';

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.message = '';
    };

    $scope.display = function() {
        $scope.show = true;
    };
}])
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Anokrize/2fvtbwd2/